# How to request rune png from riot API

Tags: javascript, request, riot-games-api

Having issues with requesting a rune specific image,

What I'm trying to find is some form of way to request a rune icon.
I've gotten as far as to find the path to the icon from [this json file](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.15.1/data/en_US/runesReforged.json). but attempts at trying to use that path, have failed. I'm sure what i'm missing is fairly basic but Its one of those days where I simply cannot figure it out. (google search lead to nothing and it looks like the rune section is [undocumented](https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/lol#data-dragon_items)).

--

### **exemplar icon:**
[image]

**exemplar path from json:** perk-images/Styles/7200_Domination.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably found, rune icons are NOT in the default ddragon path. For some reasons they are stored in a different path: https://ddragon.canisback.com/img/. For you exmaple, you can add the image url you found in the json file to the path, like https://ddragon.canisback.com/img/perk-images/Styles/7200_Domination.png. It looks like your example icon is sorcery rather than domination.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer "works" it is not the official CDN.

If you need the official CDN the paths are as follows:

https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/perk-images/Styles/Domination/Electrocute/Electrocute.png